# Saving string to database in WordPress

Tags: php, json, wordpress, sanitization

I am saving options to my database. The JSON string is returned from ajax call, and I am sanitizing it like

```
$my_settings = wp_json_encode( sanitize_text_field( wp_unslash( $_POST['data'] ) ) );
```

When I save it with `update_option` this gets saved in the database as

```
"{ \"0\": { \"settings\": { \"default\": \"0\", \"header_main_title\": \"\",...
```

Now if I only do this

```
$my_settings = sanitize_text_field( wp_unslash( $_POST['data'] ) );
```

The entry in the database will be

```
{ "0": { "settings": { "default": "0", "header_main_title": "",...
```

The second version can still be decoded using `json_decode`, since this is a JSON string after all, and doesn't have the slashed double quotes.

The thing that's bothering me is:

- Is this safe?
- Will the magic quotes have any impact on this?
- Should I use first or second way?

Comment: If you use `update_option` to save the option it is safe anyway.

Comment: It is? Because of `sanitize_option`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option value is always saving safe due to `wpdb` `update` method, not `sanitize_option`. You can save any data you want. Take a look into `update_option` code:

```
$update_args = array(
         'option_value' => $serialized_value,
);
$result = $wpdb->update( $wpdb->options, $update_args ...
```

`Update` method uses `prepare`, so it is always safe:

```
return $this->query( $this->prepare( $sql, $values ) );
```